# How to make Firebase database rules to allow only increment of 10

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My users will increment a value in the database by 10. I have tried to copy the exact example from documentation but I am still getting

> "Simulated write denied"

in the testing console.

Here are my rules:

```
{
"rules": {
"my-app": {
  "myapp": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && newData.exists() && newData.val() === data.val() + 1",
        // Only authenticated users can read and write
                // and Prevents only Delete
    "totalbyallusers": {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
    },
  }
}
}
}
```

If I remove `newData.val() === data.val() + 1` then it works. I have also tried moving `newData.val() === data.val() + 1` to "totalbyallusers" but to no avail. Basically I want that data should only be updated if it's incremented by 10. Or, less preferably, if it is not possible then it can be validated if it ends with a zero. What can I do?

The location is set to `/my-app/myapp/` and the data is this:

```
{
  "totalbyallusers" : 230
}
```

I have also tried changing location to `/my-app/myapp/totalbyallusers` but the result is same.

Comment: It looks like you're applying this rule to "myapp". So, `myapp == 0, 10, ...` is that what you wanted?

Comment: Please include your datastructure and the data/code you are using to test this.

Comment: Also have you tried using [modulus](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#_modulus) to check if the value is ending with a zero?

Comment: I want to change the value of totalbyallusers. If I move the ".write" to totalbyallusers even then the desired result is not achieved..

Comment: I have added more information in the post.

Comment: I'm not that familar with the rules syntax but shouldn't `+1` in your rule be `+10`?

Comment: you are right, but for the sake of simplicity I was using +1 as it was copied from the docs. So the example from the docs is not working

Comment: Ok so the Modulus is a very good idea and it is working. I am using `newData.val() % 10 === 0` and it is working correctly! Although I would still prefer a +10 validation so there is even lesser chance of fiddling later.

Comment: if that works it's probably something wrong with `data.val()`, e.g. it's not the right value to compare against. `% 10` seems like a fairly bad compromise since it just means that any multiple of 10 is ok, 0, -10, 324312412341340, ..

Comment: yes, I also think that there is something wrong with data.val() but I don't know what is happening here

Comment: ok so I found that it also fails on `data.exists()` whereas there is a number saved on this location

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rule to apply to your variable:

```
"totalbyallusers": {
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber()",
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null && (newData.val() != null && data.val() != null && newData.val() == data.val() + 10 || data.val() == null && newData.val() == 10)"
    }
```

You are applying rule to parent instead of the actual variable you need. Try this hopefully it will work.

Comment: still getting  Simulated write denied and now it is not even showing that on which line the error occurred

Comment: is the field currently null or has no value ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out that I was using "my-app" as the top-most parent, whereas "my-app" was the project name and was appearing on my Data tab in Firebase but was not included in the actual JSON. So I commented it out and used the same +10 technique and this time it worked!

Thank you all users who helped me in this. Here is the code which works:

```
{
"rules": {
//    "my-app": {
  "myapp": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
        // Only authenticated users can read and write
    "totalbyallusers": {
                ".validate": "newData.val() === data.val() + 10"
    }, // newData.val() % 10 === 0 // this also works but is not very safe.
  }
//    }
}
}
```